# Resubmitting a paper after rejection with changed data

Tags: paper-submission

I submitted a paper last month in a reputable high ranking journal, the paper was rejected with a chance of resubmission, the reviewer pointed out some anomalies in my data analysis and stated that my work can't be considered for publication. I run the experiments all over, and plotted new graphs. Do you think I should resubmit to the same journal? Are the reviewers going to question my new data? Is there anyone here who went through running the experiment again, finding new data and resubmitting to the same journal and got accepted for publication?

Comment: Well, have _you_ questioned your new (and old) data to understand what the differences are? Always be the worst critic of your work.

Comment: Well, have you carefully read and addressed all the reviewer comments?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on what the problems were with the old data set, why you needed to repeat it, and what changes you made to the protocol.  Were there actual mistakes that you made?  Did you add controls?  Do you have a larger data set?

I'd go so far as to say that if *you* don't understand why the original data wasn't publishable and don't have valid reasons why the second data set is better, maybe you should consider not publishing.

Another way to think about it is would you feel OK about presenting BOTH data sets in a publication, and defending the results you got for each.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you've improved the paper and its underlying data, you should probably resubmit, since they permit it. That would probably be the quickest way to get feedback on whether you have something worth publishing. Even if it is again rejected, the reasons may change which will give you further advice on how to proceed. Submitting to a different journal would start you at the beginning again and take longer in most cases.

Provide a note along with the resubmission explaining what you have done and why it correctly responds to the earlier review.

But don't waste people's efforts. Make careful evaluation yourself or within your working group.

Comment: Can it happen that the reviewers of a journal deny further re-submissions if they feel that someone has not put enough effort in working on the changes they requested? Guess it depends on the reviewer but do you know if it has already happened?

Comment: @sam Reviewers don't have that sort of power. They give advice to the editor. And it is hard to judge "effort" in any case. The question for the reviewer is to recommend publishing or not to the editor and to give advice to the authors for improvement. Authors are also often expected to detail changes to the paper making the reviewers job a bit easier.